# how do i select value from dropdownlist to mode or to controller mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

Model

```
public class Company
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    ....
    public int WorkZoneID { get; set;  }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> WorkZones { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
ViewBag.Workzones = cmpRep.GetWorkzoneDrop();
```

Repository:

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetWorkzoneDrop()
{
    SqlDataReader DR;
    DR = Ado.ExecDataReaderProc("WorkZoneSelectActive");
    List<SelectListItem> selectWorkZoneListItems = new     List<SelectListItem>();
    CompanyVMList C = new CompanyVMList();
    C.Companies = new List<Company>();
    while (DR.Read())
    {
        SelectListItem selectListItem = new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = Convert.ToString(DR["Name"]),
            Value = Convert.ToString(DR["ID"]),
        };
        selectWorkZoneListItems.Add(selectListItem);
    }
    return selectWorkZoneListItems;
}
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownList("Workzones")
```

I want to assign selected dropdownlist value to int work zone int the mode how do i select value from dropdownlist to model or to controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind your dropdownlist to property `WorkZoneID`

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.WorkZoneID, Model.Workzones)
```

and if your wanting to preselect an option, you need to set the value in the controller before you pass the model to the view. And since your model contains a property for the `SelectList`, then use it (don't use `ViewBag`)

```
Company model = new Company
{
    WorkZoneID = 1 // set to a value that matches one of your options
    Workzones = cmpRep.GetWorkzoneDrop();
};
return View(model);
```

and when you submit to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Company model)
```

the value of `model.WorkZoneID` will contain the value of the selected option.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment (and its impossible to read when you do not even format it)

Comment: i was trying to post my function that i use to insert new record i don't get it why should i use Edit function instead of my function   @StephenMuecke

Comment: You never showed any code for any methods in your question. How do you think I could possibly guess what your named it :) My code is just an example - you can call the method what ever you want

Comment: iam sorry iam just new in mvc, i did exactly like ur post  and there is an errorr:` Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: That has got absolutely nothing to do with the code in your question or the code in my answer. The error means that you accessing a property of something that is `null`. You need to step through and debug your code to identify what is `null`. My best guess is that you return the view in the POST method if `ModelState` is invalid but have forgotten to repopulate the `WorkZones` property (as I showed you in the GET method)